# Parsing HTML Checkbox checked values into php using Post

Tags: php, html, forms

I am in a silly position where I can't figure out to get the values of the checked checkboxes.

```
 <form id="civilForm" method="POST" action="form.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p>
 <label>
<input id="12D" name="programsRequested[]" type="checkbox" />
<span>12D</span>
</label>
</p>
<p>
<label>
<input id="xp" name="programsRequested[]" type="checkbox" />
<span>XPStorm</span>
</label>
</p>
<p>
<label>
<input id="autoTurn" name="programsRequested[]" type="checkbox" />
<span>AutoTurn</span>
</label>
</p>
<p>
<label>
<input id="hecras" name="programsRequested[]" type="checkbox" />
<span>HEC RAS</span>
</label>
</p>
```

Then I am using a php loop as there are a bunch more checkboxes coming.

It spins through fine, but only give me a list that says: on, on, on which correctly tells me how many I checked, however does not give me the value of the checked box.

```
$selectedPrograms  = 'None';
if(isset($_POST['programsRequested']) && is_array($_POST['programsRequested']) && count($_POST['programsRequested']) > 0){
    $selectedPrograms = implode(', ', $_POST['programsRequested']);
}
```

Is there something obvious I missing on how to get the values here?

Comment: var_dump($_POST); to see what is returned

Comment: array(4) { ["firstName"]=> string(4) "Drew" ["lastName"]=> string(3) "Vur" ["programsRequested"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "on" [1]=> string(2) "on" } ["submitCivil"]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: don't forget the `value="whatever"` attribute

Comment: just add attribute value="1" if you got value 1 in php it mean this checkbox is checked otherwise not. Also in loop you'll get only checked checkboxes

Comment: ahh the values! Not Ids my bad. I'm blind!

Comment: foreach ($array as $key => $value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add every input element value

```
<input id="12D" name="programsRequested[]" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

form not closed .

submit button also missing .

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" >
```

Comment: Sorry, it is just a part of the form, I didn't grab all the code. It is excessively long. Also thankyou, I didn't see I forgot to put values. I put ids instead! This worked perfectly